# implementing python generators with closures

Tags: python, lambda, closures

how can i get rid of the globals in fib_gen2? I don't want to use native generators or classes per this [gist](https://gist.github.com/1867106), this is an academic exercise, though I am interested improvements in any of the implementations.

```
def ftake(fnext, last):
    return [fnext() for _ in xrange(last)]

def fib_gen2():
    global a; a = 1
    global b; b = 1
    def next():
        global a; global b;
        r = a
        a, b = b, a + b
        return r
    return next

assert [1,1,2,3,5] == ftake(fib_gen2(), 5)
```

Comment: "I don't want to use native generators..." if you're doing this kind of thing at all, it's presumably because of an interest in functional programming; in which case, you should appreciate that using generators will allow you to avoid sharing state between the generator instances.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Python 3.x, you can use the [`nonlocal` statement](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-nonlocal-statement):

```
def fib_gen2():
    a = b = 1
    def next():
        nonlocal a, b
        a, b = b, a + b
        return b - a
    return next
```

In Python 2.x, you'll need to use some hack:

```
def fib_gen2():
    ab = [1, 1]
    def next():
        ab[:] = ab[1], ab[0] + ab[1]
        return ab[1] - ab[0]
    return next
```

This unsatisfactory situation was the very reason for the introduction of `nonlocal` in Python 3.x.

Python has no variable declarations, so it has to figure out the scope of each variable itself. It does so by a simple rule: If there is an assignment to a name inside a function, this name is local to that function -- except it is explicitly declared `global` or `nonlocal`. In the second example, there is no assignment to the name `ab` -- the list is modified, but the name is not reassigned. Thus the scope is the enclosing function.

Comment: whats the reasoning behind this behavior? I'm a bit confused as to why it is this way.

Comment: @DustinGetz: Added a bit of explanation.

Comment: Python really only has local and global scopes, without lexical scoping. Assigning to a variable effectively declares it as local, unless explicitly marked otherwise. You can't "re-assign" to a non-local, non-global variable in 2.x, because it isn't global (so you can't mark it), and assignment creates a new local. The hack avoids this by mutating the object contained by the `ab` variable instead of attempting to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

If I really had to avoid generators, I'd probably do this:

```
def ftake(fnext, last):
    return [fnext() for _ in xrange(last)]

def fib_gen3():
    def step():
        r = step.a
        step.a, step.b = step.b, step.a + step.b
        return r
    step.a = 1
    step.b = 1
    return step

>>> ftake(fib_gen3(), 10)
[1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of cheating so hopefully someone can give you a better answer but:

```
def ftake(fnext, last):
    return [fnext() for _ in xrange(last)]

def fib_gen2():
    fib_gen2.a = 1
    fib_gen2.b = 1
    def next():
        r = fib_gen2.a
        fib_gen2.a, fib_gen2.b = fib_gen2.b, fib_gen2.a + fib_gen2.b
        return r
    return next

assert [1,1,2,3,5] == ftake(fib_gen2(), 5)
```