# Nested iterator accessing variable from the method it's nested in

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator

I want to create an iterator that counts the length of another iterator while consuming it. 
Here is a working example of what I want to achieve:

```
from random import random

def randleniter(p):
    while random() < p:
        yield 7

count = 0

def do():
    def countiter(piter):
        global count
        for i in piter:
            count += 1
            yield i
    list(countiter(randiter(0.99))) #simulator for a different method consuming the iterator
    return count

>>> do()
81
```

However, I would have never built it like this if I intended to use a global variable. I imagined that since I can do this with nested methods:

```
def make_adder(x):
    def add(y):
        return x + y
    return add
```

I would be able to do this:

```
def do():
    count = 0
    def countiter(piter):
        for i in piter:
            count += 1
            yield i
    list(countiter(randiter(0.99)))
    return count
```

but this results in a `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'count' referenced before assignment`. When I `print locals()` from inside the `countiter` - it doesn't include `count`. 
Can I make `countiter` access `count` somehow?

Comment: why not just make a simple class

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Of course making a simple class would solve it. That's why my question wasn't "how to make this work" - I want to learn in the process :)

Comment: Obviously, a generator cannot be used in "closure-fashion".

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355179/implementing-python-generators-with-closures

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke I think it's a duplicate, not related. I've just learned exactly what closure is, so I didn't know to search for that keyword. (According to a definition I found, this isn't even really closure, since the enclosing scope didn't finish its execution)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you are describing is known as a `closure`, which is a topic completely independant from iterators and generators.
Python3.x has the `nonlocal` keyword for that (just declare `nonlocal count` in countiter to match your desired behaviour, in python 2.7, you have to emulate this via mutable objects (since inner function can `read` and `mutate` outer functions variables, just not `assign` to them).

so you can in fact do:

```
def do():
    count = [0,]
    def countiter(iter):
        for i in iter:
            count[0] += 1
            yield i
    list(countiter(randiter(0.99)))
    return count[0]
```

Comment: The code you suggested in your edit is exactly what I ran before accepting the answer. Thanks!